# C - format specifies type int but the argument has type long

Tags: c, types, arguments, long-integer

I cannot find how to fix this exercise: it's about learning character counting (I'm using the Kernighan-Ritchie edition). My issues bar says:

> ```
> warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
>     printf("%1d\n", nc);
>             ^  %1ld
> ```

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%1d\n", nc);
}
```

I use Qt Creator 3.1.1 on a Mac. Same issue on Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e).

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be hand in the future.

Comment: You make a mistake look at the `1` and `l`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , The 1 is not needed, is it?

Comment: @CoolGuy I think that this do not need to the result of count number of characters.

Answer (score 18):

The correct format specifier for a `long` is `%ld`, not `%d`. (`%d` expects an `int`.)

To fix the issue, replace

```
printf("%1d\n", nc);
```

with

```
printf("%ld\n", nc);
```

Comment: Just use `"%ld"`.  The `1` was almost certainly a mistake, `"%1ld"` is redundant and confusing.

Comment: @chqrlie , Because a number is at least one character long right?

Comment: Yes, unless the precision is `0`, the conversion yields at least 1 char.  the only exception is this: `printf("%.0d", 0);` produces no characters.